# Popup Multiple Modals from single source page

Tags: html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

a custom site on localhost and currently, in the gallery section I have some images and I am targeting to open each image in bootstrap Modal (Unique ID: modal001) and inside the modal a small description with reference image about the same project. 
I know how to do the modal thing. The only challenge is I need a single source file/page (example: modal-page.html) for all the modals and want to call any modal request from the same page.

I already tried

```html
<a href://www.website.com/modal-page.html#modal001>
```

but it's not working. 
Also, I have used ajax option but for each modal, I have to put separate ajax which is not looking appropriate. Need some expert opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to get the src of the image and put it in the modal image src..

And if you have a database where you store this images and the description for every one, you can use ajax to send the id of the image to get its description then output it in the modal through javascript

Comment: I think you dont understand the question since the question was not about importing the image ... its about the multiple modal from the single source file. please read it and I believe you may help me

Comment: Okay, I think you mean that for example if you've images when you click on them you should get this image with its description in the modal.... Am I right ?

Comment: No brother... for an instance you need to forget about image ... let me repeat my question. Lets Say I have 50 modal buttons on my page and each one will be link with unique ID with its modal form, In order to make it working I have to put all 50 modal coding on the same page.... is there any way where I can put all the modals in one single page and link each button with his unique ID using href for reference that modal contained page.